# Should I use SqlAzureExecutionStrategy with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

For stack traces such as

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 65) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   ved System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

The database in question has been configured to remedy some of the SQL deadlocks by READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT, but I wonder if the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` might simply have a bad name and apply to on-premise SQL Server as well.  For instance a note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic#execution-strategies) reads

> Execution strategies 2 and 4 are included in the SQL Server provider that ships with EF, which is in the EntityFramework.SqlServer assembly and are designed to work with SQL Server.

but with a name like `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`, I'd still like to hear someone explicitly recommend it.